# Can you use SIMBL to develop a plug-in for the iPhone's Safari?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, safari, simbl

Can you use SIMBL to develop a plug-in for the iPhone's Safari?

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot.

Comment: if you jailbreak iphone and use unofficial sdk ?

Comment: There are no input managers on iPhone, so SIMBL is not a viable option.

Comment: ok, any suggestions?

is there another solution or i must abandon my efforts? 

thanks for your responses

Comment: I can't think of anyway to do a plug-in for Safari without Apple's direct (and extremely unlikely) assistance. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

As is clear in Apple's terms of use with the iPhone SDK, no non-native code can be run by any application. This means, among other things NO PLUGINS. At all. Not for Safari, not for your own application.

Comment: It's not possible taking into account Apple's terms of use, but... would it be possible from a technical point of view ?

Comment: so if you jailbreak iphone and use unofficial sdk you can develop plug ins?

Answer (score 3):

For devices that have Cydia, you can build a [MobileSubstrate](http://svn.saurik.com/repos/menes/trunk/mobilesubstrate/) plugin. An example of such a plugin is DHowett's [Safari Download Manager](http://thebigboss.org/2009/08/02/safari-download-manager-100-is-out/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a Safari webplugin, which loads a custom UIView to display content based on MIME types.

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Internet_Plug-Ins