# Plug In To Other Applications (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone

I'm pretty sure that due to the Application Sandbox, none of this is possible, but...

I am working on an application that operates on text that the user inputs. Aside from forcing the user to copy and paste from another application or type in text, what other options exist for getting text? To be more specific:

- Is there any way to get the user to "pass" an email to my app? I can imagine a hacky solution where I have the user mail it to a server on the Net, and then I expose the mail from a server-side application, but I'd like something a bit more direct.
- Is there any way to get to the user's mail inbox without asking them to put in their credentials?
- Is there any way to plug-in to Safari, so that I can send web pages "over" to the app? I don't mean a full plugin, which [I know is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330700/safari-plug-in-for-iphone).

I'm trying to think of creative ways to solve this problem of how to get text into my app, so any ideas would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Iphone SDK Forum: "Apps can't read each others files - but you could use a URL scheme to launch one app from another. Any parameters in the URL would be passed."

It's what my gut was telling me, but i wanted to go verify before saying..officially, no.  The Sandbox isolates each program..

You can pass via URL text strings, but that's about it.  I haven't seen any app which hacks around this limitation, but that just may be none of them surviving the app submission process.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21099-sharing-data-between-applications.html

Comment: Sorry i couldn't be more help.  :-(